# Google Plus - Getting Error While Fetching Friends Details

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

Hi i'm successfully loged in google plus. Now i'm trying to fetch friends details like emails, image, name.But getting error.

Please any one could help me, where i'm making mistake -

I tried this code -

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
               error: (NSError *) error {

    self.plusService.authorizer = auth;

    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Email---> %@\n\n",[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.userEmail]);
    NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object     ---> %@\n\n",error, auth);
```

**// 1. Create a |GTLServicePlus| instance to send a request to Google+.**

```
    GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init] ;

    plusService.retryEnabled = YES;
```

**// 2. Set a valid |GTMOAuth2Authentication| object as the authori zer.**

```
    [plusService setAuthorizer:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication];
```

**// 3. Use the "v1" version of the Google+ API.***

```
    plusService.apiVersion = @"v1";
    GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleListWithUserId:@"me" collection:kGTLPlusCollectionVisible];

    [plusService executeQuery:query
            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                GTLPlusPeopleFeed *person,
                                NSError *error) {
        if (error)
             {
               GTMLoggerError(@"Error: %@", error);
             }
             else {

                 NSArray *peopleList = person.items;
                 NSLog(@"--People_List--->%@",peopleList);

             }}];

  }
```

Getting Error -

```
[lvl=3] __41-[ViewController finishedWithAuth:error:]_block_invoke() Error: Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Invalid Credentials)" UserInfo=0x7b0a1d10 {error=Invalid Credentials, GTLStructuredError=GTLErrorObject 0x7b089360: {message:"Invalid Credentials" code:401 data:[1]}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=(Invalid Credentials)}
```

Comment: Error it self saying that there is some error of authentication in Google+.

Answer (score 0):

for Fetching Friends Details you can use Google Contacts api

in that use

```
#import "GDataFeedContact.h"
#import "GDataContacts.h"
```

class file

then use this code to get data

```
 -(void)getGoogleContacts
    {
        GDataServiceGoogleContact *service = [self contactService];
        GDataServiceTicket *ticket;

        BOOL shouldShowDeleted = TRUE;


        const int kBuncha = 2000;

        NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleContact contactFeedURLForUserID:kGDataServiceDefaultUser];

        GDataQueryContact *query = [GDataQueryContact contactQueryWithFeedURL:feedURL];
        [query setShouldShowDeleted:shouldShowDeleted];
        [query setMaxResults:kBuncha];

        ticket = [service fetchFeedWithQuery:query
                                    delegate:self
                           didFinishSelector:@selector(contactsFetchTicket:finishedWithFeed:error:)];

        [self setContactFetchTicket:ticket];
    }

    - (void)setContactFetchTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
    {
        mContactFetchTicket = ticket;
    }

    - (GDataServiceGoogleContact *)contactService
    {
        static GDataServiceGoogleContact* service = nil;

        if (!service) {
            service = [[GDataServiceGoogleContact alloc] init];

            [service setShouldCacheResponseData:YES];
            [service setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks:YES];
        }


  //pass the useremail and password.here

        NSString *username = @"youremai@gmail";
        NSString *password = @"yourpassword";


        [service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:username
                                       password:password];

        return service;
    }


    - (void)contactsFetchTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
               finishedWithFeed:(GDataFeedContact *)feed
                          error:(NSError *)error {

        if (error) {
            NSDictionary *userInfo = [error userInfo];
            NSLog(@"Contacts Fetch error :%@", [userInfo objectForKey:@"Error"]);
            if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"Error"] isEqual:@"BadAuthentication"]) {

                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!"
                                                                    message:@"Authentication Failed"
                                                                   delegate:self
                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alertView show];
            } else {
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!"
                                                                    message:@"Failed to get Contacts."
                                                                   delegate:self
                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alertView show];
            }
        } else {

            NSArray *contacts = [feed entries];
            NSLog(@"Contacts Count: %d ", [contacts count]);
            [googleContacts removeAllObjects];
            for (int i = 0; i < [contacts count]; i++) {
                GDataEntryContact *contact = [contacts objectAtIndex:i];

                // Name
                NSString *ContactName = [[[contact name] fullName] contentStringValue];
                NSLog(@"Name    :  %@", ContactName);

                // Email
                GDataEmail *email = [[contact emailAddresses] objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *ContactEmail =  @"";
                if (email && [email address]) {
                    ContactEmail = [email address];
                    NSLog(@"EmailID :  %@", ContactEmail);
                }

                // Phone
                GDataPhoneNumber *phone = [[contact phoneNumbers] objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *ContactPhone = @"";
                if (phone && [phone contentStringValue]) {
                    ContactPhone = [phone contentStringValue];
                    NSLog(@"Phone   :  %@", ContactPhone);
                }

                // Address
                GDataStructuredPostalAddress *postalAddress = [[contact structuredPostalAddresses] objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *address = @"";
                if (postalAddress) {
                    NSLog(@"formattedAddress   :  %@", [postalAddress formattedAddress]);
                    address = [postalAddress formattedAddress];
                }

                // Birthday
                NSString *dob = @"";
                if ([contact birthday]) {
                    dob = [contact birthday];
                    NSLog(@"dob   :  %@", dob);
                }

                if (!ContactName || !(ContactEmail || ContactPhone) ) {
                    NSLog(@"Empty Contact Fields. Not Adding.");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!ContactEmail ) {
                        ContactEmail = @"";
                    }
                    if (!ContactPhone ) {
                        ContactPhone = @"";
                    }
                    NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"name", @"emailId", @"phoneNumber", @"address", @"dob", nil];
                    NSArray *objs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:ContactName, ContactEmail, ContactPhone, address, dob, nil];
                    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objs forKeys:keys];

                    [googleContacts addObject:dict];
                }
            }
            NSSortDescriptor *descriptor =
            [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
            [googleContacts sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor, nil]];

      get the more info refer this http://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2013/07/ios-google-contacts/4/
```